# Google+ Share Plugin - getting "Exception thrown and not caught" in IE, works fine in Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, share, google-plus

I'm just trying to add the Google+ share plugin to an application and it works fine in firefox but I get the following error in IE - "Exception thrown and not caught"

The following is the very basic code that I run on both firefox and IE, work fine in Firefox but dies in IE9:

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'en-GB', parsetags: 'onload'}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="24"></div>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate. -->
<script type="text/javascript">gapi.plus.go();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated or if you can redirect me to someone that can give me some insight would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Mary O'Connor

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're seeing is a bug. The share button is throwing an exception because your test page has no DTD.  Add this to the first line of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Now your share button will work :)

I've [filed this bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=217) in the Google+ platform issue tracker. You can star it to subscribe to updates.

Comment: Jenny, Thank you so much for that! That did the trick. Have a super day! :-)